# Casting a C pointer to a struct, in Rust

Tags: c, pointers, rust, ffi

I have bindings in Rust for a library in C and they aren't complete.

In C code I have a macros defined, simplified, like this:

```
  #define MY_MACROS1(PTR) (((my_struct1 *) (PTR))->field1.field2 >> 2)
```

I need to achieve the same thing in Rust.

I have a Rust binding definition for `my_struct1`. And I have a pointer

```
  let my_ptr1: usize = unsafe { get_a_pointer_from_c(); }
```

How can I cast a pointer `my_ptr1` to `my_struct1` or rather to `my_struct1 *` ?

Rust binding to `get_a_pointer_from_c()` returns a pointer of type `usize`, note.

Comment: Why not do a function on C to return the value that looks like to be an int ?

Comment: What keeps you from doing it exactly the same way as shown?

Comment: I believe the ` \ ` is a typo or a copy-paste error, or an accident concerning newline white space.

Answer (score 2):

- Option 1 would be what Ôrel suggested: have the C side expose the proper accessor as a function, and call that from Rust.
- option 2 is to define the C struct on the Rust side and cast your pointer to a pointer / ref to that on the Rust side e.g.

  ```rust
  let mut p;
  let r = unsafe {
      p = ptr::NonNull::new(
          get_pointer_from_c() as *mut YourType
      ).unwrap();
      p.as_mut()
  };
  ```